# how to add a column in yii gridview with each value having different button color

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

Thanks I really appreciate the help, but please I am trying to display a different button colour depending on the value of the status and I have tried different ways but it isn't working.

```
[  
    'label' => 'Status',  
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {  
        if ($model->status = "Approved") {
            $sta = "btn-success";
        } elseif ($model->status = "Pending...") {
            $sta = "btn-info";
        } else {
            $sta = "btn-danger";
        }
        $btn = '<a href="' . Url::home() . 'site/index?id=' . $model->id .'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Status" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-sm'.$sta.' ">'.$model->status.'</a>';   
        return $btn;   
    },  
],
```

this one only see the first only displays "approved " for all the value and makes them all one colour..

I also did this

```
[  
    'label' => 'Status',  
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {  
        foreach ($model->status as $status) {
            if ($model->status = "Approved") {
                $sta = "btn-success";
                $btn = '<a href="' . Url::home() . 'site/index?id=' . $model->id .'" 
                        data-toggle="tooltip" title="Status" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-sm 
                        '.$sta.' ">'.$model->status.'</a>';   
                return $btn;   
            } elseif ($model->status = "Pending...") {
                $sta = "btn-info";
                $btn = '<a href="' . Url::home() . 'site/index?id=' . $model->id .'" 
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Status" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-sm 
                            '.$sta.' ">'.$model->status.'</a>';   
                return $btn;   
            } else {
                $sta = "btn-danger";
                $btn = '<a href="' . Url::home() . 'site/index?id=' . $model->id .'" 
                        data-toggle="tooltip" title="Status" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-sm 
                        '.$sta.' ">'.$model->status.'</a>';   
                return $btn;   
            }     
        }      
    },  
],
```

but this one is giving an error that invalid parameter passed inside the foreach loop

Comment: You should read [Url helper guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-url) - you should never create URLs in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the single `=` sign to 3 `===` signs.

So like this

```
if ($model->status === "Approved") {
    $sta = "btn-success";
} elseif ($model->status === "Pending...") {
    $sta = "btn-info";
} else {
    $sta = "btn-danger";
}
```

By using only a single `=` you're assigning the value to the variable, so the first option will always be true.

---

The second one gives an error because `$model->status` contains a string value, not an array, so it can't be used in a foreach.

Comment: Thanks jagsler it worked.. I really appreciate..  Thanks So much